# MongoDB selecting documents where the maximum time is less than a constant

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to select a set of documents from a MongoDB where the maximum time is less than a timeout.

So like this for sql

```
select distinct item_id where max(time) < 140034857
```

Basically it's a collection of successful comms operations for devices and I'm looking for the ones which have had none in the last hour.

Comment: corrected the sql, feeling it must be possible using the pipeline, just not sure how

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `$lt` operator to find documents where the value of the `time` key is less than a specified value.

```
db.Collection.find({"time" : {$lt: 140034857}})
```